# Problems with rendering grass that is created by the strand renderer in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

I have an Nvidia 760 GTX and when I try to render my image with GPU compute and F12 it does not produce any output at all.

When I switch to CPU render I get the following image

[image]

Which is not at all what I have created

When I set the viewport to render it looks like this

[image: http://i.imgur.com/4g0JTa4.jpg]
[.blend](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/29540)

Comment: It sounds like your GPU ran out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by myself. The problem was a setting in the 'Children' tab. It seems that the renderer in the viewport takes the number from 'Display' and  not from 'Render'.